# Custom Handlebars.js helper not returning options.fn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I'm trying to make a `if x in JSON` statement in Handlebars. It works, except that it doesn't return the right option.
This is index.html:

```
   {{#dinsdag}}
            {{#each uitval2}}
                {{@key}}
            {{/each}}
            {{#isIn 7 uitval2}}
                <p>klopt</p>
            {{else}}
                <p>mwah</p>
            {{/isIn}}
   {{/dinsdag}}
```

This is data.js:

```
$(function(){
    var templateScript = $("#entry-template").html();
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);
    var context = {  "dinsdag": {
                        "uitval2": {
                          "7": "1",
                          "9": "1",
                          "11": "1"
                        },}}
    var html = theTemplate(context);
    $('.test').html(html);
    $(document.body).append(html);
})
```

And finally this is helper.js, where the problem should be.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isIn', function(waarde, inWaarde, options){
$.each($.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(inWaarde)), function(k, v) {
    if (parseInt(k) === parseInt(waarde)){
        console.log("true");
        return options.fn(this);
    }
});
    console.log("false");
    return options.inverse(this);
```

});

It does return `True` in the console, but it returns the `else` option in the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning inside the `each()` function, but that doesn't make your helper return false.

But you can use a flag outside of `each()` to determine the output. Like so:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isIn', function(waarde, inWaarde, options){

    // Start with false assumption
    var isTrue = false;

    $.each($.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(inWaarde)), function(k, v) {
        if (parseInt(k) === parseInt(waarde)){

            // Set outer flag
            isTrue = true;

            // Break loop
            return false;
        }
    });


    if (isTrue) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

Some more info from the docs (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Comment: Thanks, I'm used to python where this isn't a  problem. I can't give the bounty yet, you'll get it tomorrow!